# Wasmd isn't installed

Tags: rust-wasm

I have tried to install wasmd on Ubuntu.

```
git clone https://github.com/CosmWasm/wasmd.git
cd wasmd
git checkout v0.23.0
make install
```

But when I tried `wasmd version`, I met `wasmd: command not found`.
It seems like the problem of `PATH` setting but I don't know what to do.

Is there anybody who would help me with solving this issue?

Comment: Could you add the output of the `make install` command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the go PATH.

Find where go is installed.
And, `vi ~·bash_profile`

**export GOPATH="/Users/{Username}/go"**

**export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"**

:wq

`source ~/.bash_profile`

You can check it with the `echo $GOPATH/bin` command.

> $GOPATH may change when the terminal restarts....

Comment: GitHub user Buckram123 let me know about this, which helped get me out of this situation: `export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin`